# rails puma - command without config file - path to error log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I am running puma like this:

```
puma -e production -b unix://blahblah.sock
```

setting up configs etc going to take a little more time, so I want to put into production using this.  Ofcourse, using nginx.

Where can I find error logs ?

Or any other command to include for error logs to work ?

Answer (score 5):

It's a good practice to create `config/puma.rb` file, where you can manage related configuration settings.

**Set up puma**

Puma can be configured just by providing command-line arguments, but it's more convenient to bake the configuration settings into a configuration file and then provide that file with a single -C command line directive. A simple `puma.rb` that works with MRI Ruby is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

# start puma with:
# RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C ./config/puma.rb

application_path = Rails.root
railsenv = 'production'
directory application_path
environment railsenv
daemonize true
pidfile "#{application_path}/tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.pid"
state_path "#{application_path}/tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.state"
stdout_redirect
"#{application_path}/log/puma-#{railsenv}.stdout.log",
"#{application_path}/log/puma-#{railsenv}.stderr.log"
threads 0, 16
bind "unix://#{application_path}/tmp/sockets/#{railsenv}.socket"
```

*For more info please refer - [Puma and Nginx production stack](http://wagn.org/Puma_and_Nginx_production_stack)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing config file too. I will try it out and mark it answer. For now, +1 :)

Comment: Getting error at this line - "#{application_path}/log/puma-#{railsenv}.stdout.log", may be some typo? can u tell me ?

Comment: what's the error ? can you show the stack trace?
I guess you need to change few variables here like `application_path = Rails.root`

Comment: app path needs to be hardcoded? Better use `pidfile "tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.pid"`.